# Copy files `*XXX*` to `*YYY*`

Tags: bash, copy-paste, cp

I have a bunch of files with a `XXX` string in the name, like:

- `someXXXfile`
- `someotherXXXfile`
- ...

I want to take all these files and copy them in the same folder, changing `XXX` with another string `YYY`, so I obtain in the same folder:

- `someXXXfile`
- `someotherXXXfile`
- ...
- `someYYYfile`
- `someotherYYYfile`
- ...

How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In BASH you can do:

```
for f in *XXX*; do echo mv -i "$f" "${f/XXX/YYY}"; done
```

If you have `rename` utility then use:

```
rename 's/XXX/YYY/' *XXX*
```

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Please always use `mv -i` for bulk moves like this, so it'll notify you of any name conflicts rather than silently overwriting files.

Answer (score 2):

Use the super helpful `rename` command. Think of it as rename from XXX to YYY on all files.

```
rename XXX YYY *
```

If you are looking to *copy* in addition to move, copy to some subdirectory first and then move back.